# How to use jQuery in a facebook application

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook

I finished my application in locale and I want to integrate it in Facebook creating an app. My application works well, but when I try to load it from Facebook it doen't work.

I've read that there's some problem including JavaScript that are not FBJS.

I'm not using the Facebook markup language but mine ( jQuery UI and simply html + php ).

Can someone provide me with a link to a guide that explains how to create an app that uses jQuery or other js framework?

Answer (score 4):

Remember that when you code JavaScript for Facebook you must write it in a way that conforms to [FBJS](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS), their rationale is *"We built FBJS to empower developers with all the functionality they need, and to protect our users' privacy at the same time."*

[FBJQRY](http://code.google.com/p/fbjqry/), is a library that aims to provide jQuery-like syntax in FBJS, and may be the answer to your question for non-iframe Facebook Applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can include not-allowed-things like google maps, charts, JavaScript menus, etc in your app by using fb iframe tag and then manipulate the stuff accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

#### You are not allowed to use jQuery or Prototype in a Facebook FBML application.

There may be technical ways around this, but as far as I know nobody has succeeded. Your application may be better suited to live outside of Facebook using Facebook connect.

Comment: Facebook allow you to use jQuery, proto ecc, if you use IFrame application and not FBML. The problem is that I don't find any tutorial about this. Like fb want to allow you to use only FBML