# Can I use jQuery with Facebook apps?

Tags: jquery, facebook

I've been scouring various sites looking for info on how to do this but haven't found anything.  Has anyone done this?  Suggestions on where to look for info on how to use it?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679775/how-to-use-jquery-in-a-facebook-application

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a couple of types/purposes when creating a Facebook App, and I believe your question is about [Apps on Facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas).

**UPDATE:** On [March, 11, 2011](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462#fbml_roadmap) Facebook stopped allowing new FBML apps to be created. So back to your questions:

> Can I use jQuery with Facebook apps?

**YES**, you can use any JS library in your Apps (Canvas, tab or website) since the iframe is the ***only*** canvas type now.

---

Now facebook *still* gives you the choice between developing your Facebook application canvas either in IFrame or FBML **BUT** they are encouraging developers to use IFrame as they are in the process of deprecating the [`FBML`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/):

> **We are in the process of deprecating
>   FBML**. If you are building a new
>   application on Facebook.com, please
>   implement your application using HTML,
>   JavaScript and CSS. You can use our
>   JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins to
>   embedded many of the same social
>   features available in FBML. While
>   there is still functionality that we
>   have not ported over yet, we are no
>   longer adding new features to FBML.

Also as you can notice on their [Javascript-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/connect-js), that one of the example is actually using the jQuery library!

SO, *can I use jQuery with Facebook Apps?*
**YES**, .... and **NO**!
**YES**: you can use it inside your **Canvas Page** if you choose IFrame AND
<strike>**NO**: you can't use it inside your Page Tabs, yet:</strike>

> Broadly, a Page Tab is loaded in
>   exactly the same way as a Canvas Page,
>   with one **(large) exception**. Page Tabs
>   still use our FBML infrastructure,
>   rather than using an iframe in the
>   browser. In order to correctly render
>   FBML tags, our servers need to process
>   the content at the Tab URL before it
>   is sent to the user's browser. In
>   practice, you can still use HTML,
>   JavaScript (using FBJS) and CSS for
>   your content, but there are a number
>   of quirks.
>
> We are in the process of moving our
>   Page Tab infrastructure a pure iframe
>   solution currently, but we do not
>   expect to complete that work **until Q1
>   2011**. In the meantime, we recommend that developers to minimize the amount
>   of FBML code they can add to their
>   apps.

As you can see, we are ***IN*** the first quarter of 2011 so Page Tab IFrame support is around the corner!

**EDIT:**
[***IFrame support for Facebook Pages was added!!***](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The preferred method for Facebook Canvas Apps is to use an iframe as the means for pulling in the app content. In this case, you are able to use jQuery within your application just as you normally would.

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas for more info.

Comment: Hmm, so could I use a canvas app to create a new tab?

Comment: Yes, certainly. In the app settings you specify which script you want to appear in the tab. Then when you add the app to your page that script will be what loads into the tab. Now, there are some restrictions of what can actually load into a tab. The tab actually might cause you some problems with jQuery. The app I recently built did not require much functionality in the tab itself. But, again, once on a canvas page jQuery works per the usual.

Answer (score 0):

All new Apps on Facebook are just iframes, so the answer is absolutely yes, just like you can use JQuery in any web page.