# How do you access scroll property, using jQuery, for the parent window in an iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, scroll, parent

Basically I am tring to figure out if the parent frame is being scrolled or not.

I thought it would be something like this but that didn't work;

```
$(window.top).scroll(function () { alert('I\'m scrolling!') });
```

UPDATE: It's a Facebook App.

Anyone?

Comment: Does the parent also have jQuery included? If so, you might try `window.top.$(window.top).scroll` if that works (not sure).

Comment: Tried that as well, in a test I found that worked if both had jQuery...It's a Facebook App. and is telling me it can't find the property $ or jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Sublet,

Quoting Artlung from another post,

"Remember that when you code JavaScript for Facebook you must write it in a way that conforms to FBJS, their rationale is "We built FBJS to empower developers with all the functionality they need, and to protect our users' privacy at the same time."

FBJQRY, is a library that aims to provide jQuery-like syntax in FBJS, and may be the answer to your question for non-iframe Facebook Applications."

[How to use jQuery in a facebook application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679775/how-to-use-jquery-in-a-facebook-application)